# HTML audio Element how to replay?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I setup a HTML5 page, that include a  node.
The page will to playing a music(mp3 format),but it just play sound to end, and I use javascript to control audio element,even so,I can't replay it and only STOP.

Does HTML5 audio Element support REPLAY? And how to?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

please read this

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/

and for replay event

you can set option, on **replay** click

```
audioElement.currentTime=0;
audioElement.play();
```

Comment: It doesn't work on every browser. `.load()` and then `.play()` always works, but it might use more data...

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
  audio.pause() // important!!!
  audio.currentTime = 0
  audio.play()
```

Answer (score 4):

The suggestions above did not worked for me or where not applicable. I needed to replay sound when my code needed to do it.

The following code worked (at least chrome):

audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioSrc);
 audioElement.play();

in other words, setting the src attribute again, then play() did the job

Comment: This is working but makes a new request for the sound res every time.

Comment: @valkirilov But it works around https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121765

Answer (score 4):

If the server hosting the video does not support seeking on client (HTTP RangeRequest), the command

```
audioElement.currentTime=0;
```

from @JapanPro's answer is silently ignored in Chromium. This behavior is filled as [crbug #121765](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121765).

There is a [handy guide on MDN how to configure your server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) to play nice. But if you cannot, I had success with doing

```
audioElement.load();
```

which unsurprisingly reloads the audio source and seeks to the start as a side effect. Not nice, but it is quite intuitive and it works.

source: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#loading-the-media-resource

Comment: `audioThing.load()` is the _only_ approach that will let Safari rewind an audio clip. Once you do `audioThing.play()` in Safari, it loses track of where it was, setting `audioThing.currentTime=0;` doesn't work, and neither does `audioThing.volume=1;` These are longstanding Apple bugs – for years now. Grrr

Answer (score 3):

The html5 audio element has a loop attribute set it to loop=loop

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp

Comment: but I just want to a audio played, then it play again when wait user click

Answer (score 1):

don't use `node.load()` this is way too slow for slow devices.

To stop, you should just use:

```
node.currentTime = 0
```

To replay you can do:

```
node.currentTime = 0
node.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="audio/flute_c_long_01.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<a href="javascript:play_single_sound();">Play 5-sec sound on single channel</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play_single_sound() {
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
    }
</script>
```

Ref: http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can just set `audioElement.loop='true';`