# How do I play and pause the audio with a button?

Tags: javascript, php, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

How do I create a single button (button will be displayed in index.php) that plays AND pauses audio source node in JavaScript?

So essentially you have a button that plays an audio, and when clicked again, it pauses the song...
EDIT: index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta name="description" content="HTML5 Audio Spectrum Visualizer">
    <title>HTML5 Audio API showcase | Audio visualizer</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="fileWrapper" class="file_wrapper">
            <div id="info">
                HTML5 Audio API showcase | An Audio Viusalizer
            </div>
            <label for="uploadedFile">Drag&drop or select a file to play:  
</label>
            <input type="file" id="uploadedFile"></input>
        </div>
        <div id="visualizer_wrapper">
            <canvas id='canvas' width="800" height="350"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <small></small>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5_audio_visualizer.js">    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is part of the JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    new Visualizer().ini();
};
var Visualizer = function() {
    this.file = null; //the current file
    this.fileName = null; //the current file name
    this.audioContext = null;
    this.source = null; //the audio source
    this.info = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML; //this used to 
    upgrade the UI information
    this.infoUpdateId = null; //to sotore the setTimeout ID and clear the 
    interval
    this.animationId = null;
    this.status = 0; //flag for sound is playing 1 or stopped 0
    this.forceStop = false;
    this.allCapsReachBottom = false;
}
Visualizer.prototype = {
    ini: function() {
        this._prepareAPI();
        this._addEventListner();
    },
    _prepareAPI: function() {
        //fix browser vender for AudioContext and requestAnimationFrame
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext     
        || window.mozAudioContext || window.msAudioContext;
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||     
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame || 
        window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame || 
        window.msCancelAnimationFrame;
        try {
            this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
        } catch (e) {
            this._updateInfo('!Your browser does not support AudioContext', 
        false);
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
    _addEventListner: function() {
        var that = this,
            audioInput = document.getElementById('uploadedFile'),
            dropContainer = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        //listen the file upload
        audioInput.onchange = function() {
            if (that.audioContext===null) {return;};

            //the if statement fixes the file selction cancle, because the 
        onchange will trigger even the file selection been canceled
            if (audioInput.files.length !== 0) {
                //only process the first file
                that.file = audioInput.files[0];
                that.fileName = that.file.name;
                if (that.status === 1) {
                    //the sound is still playing but we upload another file, so 
        set the forceStop flag to true
                    that.forceStop = true;
                };
                document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 1;
                that._updateInfo('Uploading', true);
                //once the file is ready,start the visualizer
                that._start();
            };
        };
        //listen the drag & drop
        dropContainer.addEventListener("dragenter", function() {
            document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 1;
            that._updateInfo('Drop it on the page', true);
        }, false);
        dropContainer.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            //set the drop mode
            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        }, false);
        dropContainer.addEventListener("dragleave", function() {
            document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 0.2;
            that._updateInfo(that.info, false);
        }, false);
        dropContainer.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            if (that.audioContext===null) {return;};
            document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 1;
            that._updateInfo('Uploading', true);
            //get the dropped file
            that.file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
            if (that.status === 1) {
                document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 1;
                that.forceStop = true;
            };
            that.fileName = that.file.name;
            //once the file is ready,start the visualizer
            that._start();
        }, false);
    },
    _start: function() {
        //read and decode the file into audio array buffer 
            var that = this,
                file = this.file,
                fr = new FileReader();
           fr.onload = function(e) {
                var fileResult = e.target.result;
                var audioContext = that.audioContext;
                if (audioContext === null) {
                    return;
                };
                that._updateInfo('Decoding the audio', true);
                audioContext.decodeAudioData(fileResult, function(buffer) {
                that._updateInfo('Decode succussfully,start the visualizer', 
                true);
                    that._visualize(audioContext, buffer);
                }, function(e) {
                  that._updateInfo('!Fail to decode the file', false);
                    console.log(e);
                });
            };
            fr.onerror = function(e) {
                that._updateInfo('!Fail to read the file', false);
                console.log(e);
            };
            //assign the file to the reader
            this._updateInfo('Starting read the file', true);
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        },
        _visualize: function(audioContext, buffer) {
            var audioBufferSouceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource(),
                analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser(),
                that = this;
            //connect the source to the analyser
            audioBufferSouceNode.connect(analyser);
            //connect the analyser to the destination(the speaker), or we won't             
            hear the sound
            analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
            //then assign the buffer to the buffer source node
            audioBufferSouceNode.buffer = buffer;
            //play the source
            if (!audioBufferSouceNode.start) {
            audioBufferSouceNode.start = audioBufferSouceNode.noteOn //in old 
            browsers use noteOn method
            audioBufferSouceNode.stop = audioBufferSouceNode.noteOff //in old
            browsers use noteOn method
            };
            //stop the previous sound if any
            if (this.animationId !== null) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationId);
            }
            if (this.source !== null) {
                this.source.stop(0);
            }
            audioBufferSouceNode.start(0);
            this.status = 1;
            this.source = audioBufferSouceNode;
            audioBufferSouceNode.onended = function() {
                that._audioEnd(that);
            };
            this._updateInfo('Playing ' + this.fileName, false);
            this.info = 'Playing ' + this.fileName;
            document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 0.2;
            this._drawSpectrum(analyser);
        },
        ...
```

How do I go about doing it? Also is it possible to create a basic volume slider-bar?

Comment: Is all that you want to do play and pause a song? (why are you using webaudio)

Comment: Any reason why not to use the [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML audio Element how to replay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005472/html-audio-element-how-to-replay)

Comment: @jcuenod  html5 web audio api is being used to create a audio visualizer.


SpencerWieczorek well if i tried it, it didn't work, If you can get it to work, than that's great!  and that for the "HTML Audio Element how to replay?" thanks jcuenod i think that is what I am looking for, but how would i go about implementing that in this code, since im particulary new to javascript? Would you be able to do that?

JimmyBreck-McKye Thank you for your vague opinion, but it is not needed, thanks, also it's not my code, the 'credit section' has been edited out by an editor.

Comment: If you want it for a visualizer, the audioelement is not going to work for you. Take a look at this demo though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/html5-audio-spectrum-visualizer

Comment: @jcuenod that's the code I've geen, That's the same visualizer I've posted about. That's also in fact the exact site I got it from too. So the question still remains the same, how do you create these buttons using javascript? Maybe it is possible to create buttons in php then once they are pressed, it activates a pause action in javascript visualizer...? Same goes for the play button, volume slider button?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek don't think that work, I've tried it, well you can try it yourself maybe I've implemented audio element the wrong way. If you can fix it, that's great..I'll mark yours as the answer then...