# play same number of sound as the exact time

Tags: javascript

I want to play the same number of sounds as the exact time.
But this don't work. What's wrong?
(for test, I try to play at second 0)

```
function pendula() {
    var Digital=new Date();
    var hours=Digital.getHours();
    var minutes=Digital.getMinutes();
    var seconds=Digital.getSeconds();

    mysound="<audio id='sound' src='../audio/Clock.mp3' autoplay='autoplay'></audio>";

    if (seconds===0) {
      for (var i=1; i<=hours; i++) {   
       document.getElementById("pendula").innerHTML=mysound;
      }
      setTimeout("pendula()",1000);
    }
   }
   pendula();
```

Can somebody help me, please? Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you inserting an `<audio>` over and over again? [You can just replay the sound from the existing element.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005472/html-audio-element-how-to-replay)

Comment: I did not understand very much, so I don't know how to use it... :(